# C++: Implementation of the Numerov Method for the 1D square well

Tags: c++, numerical-methods

I want to solve the Schrodinger via the Numerov Method but I had some troubles. I'm programing in C++, so here is my code:

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

double x_min=-4.0 , x_max=4.0;
int N=2000;             
double r=(x_max-x_min)/(1.0*N); 
double d=2.0;
double p=0.4829;    // 2m/(hbar^2)
double Vo=20.0;     // Altura del pozo

double x_m=0.1;     //Matching point
int i_x_m=(x_m-x_min)/r;

double Control=-123456789;

double SlopeLeft,SlopeRight;

double PAR;

double K2(double x, double E);
double NumerovL(int i, double k21, double k22, double k23, double Y[]);
double NumerovR(int i, double k21, double k22, double k23, double Y[]);
double FuncLeft(double E, double Y[]);
double FuncRight(double E, double Y[]);
void PrintFunc(double Y[]);
void Normalizar(double Y[]);
double f(double E, double Y[]);
double Biseccion(double a, double b, double Y[]);

//=========================MAIN===============================

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{  

double Y[N+1];       // Función de Onda

double paso=0.02;    // Escala en la que se varia la energía
double Eo=0;

for(double E=0 ; E<=Vo ; E+=paso) // Cálculo de las funciones IMPARES
{
    PAR=-1;
    Eo=Biseccion(E,E+paso,Y);

    if(Eo != Control && SlopeRight*SlopeLeft<0.) 
    {
        Y[i_x_m]=FuncRight(Eo,Y);
        Y[i_x_m]=FuncLeft(Eo,Y);


        Normalizar(Y);

        PrintFunc(Y);   
    }

}


for(double E=0 ; E<=Vo ; E+=paso)  // Cálculo de las funciones PARES
{
    PAR=1;
    Eo=Biseccion(E,E+paso,Y);

    if(Eo != Control && SlopeRight*SlopeLeft>0.)
    {
        Y[i_x_m]=FuncRight(Eo,Y);
        Y[i_x_m]=FuncLeft(Eo,Y);

        Normalizar(Y);

        PrintFunc(Y);   
    }
}


  return 0;
}

 //=========================FUNCIONES===============================

 double K2(double x, double E) 
 {
  double k2;

if(fabs(x)<=d)
{
    k2=p*E;
    return k2;
}
else
{
    k2=p*(E-Vo);
    return k2;
}
}

double NumerovL(int i, double k21, double k22, double k23, double Y[]) 
{ // Para la función de Onda Izquierda
double A1,B1,C1,N;
A1=2.0*(1.0-(5.0/12.0)*r*r*k21)*Y[i-1];
B1=(1.0+(1.0/12.0)*r*r*k22)*Y[i-2];
C1=1.0+(1.0/12.0)*r*r*k23;
N=(A1-B1)/(C1);
return N;
}

double NumerovR(int i, double k21, double k22, double k23, double Y[]) 
{ // Para la función de Onda Derecha
double A1,B1,C1,N;
A1=2.0*(1.0-(5.0/12.0)*r*r*k21)*Y[i+1];
B1=(1.0+(1.0/12.0)*r*r*k22)*Y[i+2];
C1=1.0+(1.0/12.0)*r*r*k23;
N=PAR*(A1-B1)/(C1);
return N;
}

double FuncLeft(double E, double Y[])
{
double k21,k22,k23,Yleft,b;

b=sqrt(p*(Vo-E));

Y[0]=exp(b*x_min);
Y[1]=exp(b*(x_min+r));


for(int i=2 ; i<i_x_m ; i++) // Se calcula la función de Onda Izquierda
{
    k21=K2(x_min+(i-1)*r,E);
    k22=K2(x_min+(i-2)*r,E);
    k23=K2(x_min+i*r,E);

    Y[i]=NumerovL(i,k21,k22,k23,Y);

    if(i==i_x_m-1) //Función de Onda Izquierda en el Matching point
    {
        k21=K2(x_min+(i)*r,E);
        k22=K2(x_min+(i-1)*r,E);
        k23=K2(x_min+(i+1)*r,E);

        Yleft=NumerovL(i+1,k21,k22,k23,Y);
    }
}

SlopeLeft=(Yleft-Y[i_x_m-1])/r;

return Yleft;
}

double FuncRight(double E, double Y[])
{
double k21,k22,k23,Yright,b;

b=sqrt(p*(Vo-E));

Y[N]=PAR*exp(-b*(x_min+N*r));   
Y[N-1]=PAR*exp(-b*(x_min+(N-1)*r));

for(int i=N-2 ; i>i_x_m; i--) // Se calcula la función de Onda Derecha
{
    k21=K2(x_min+(i+1)*r,E);
    k22=K2(x_min+(i+2)*r,E);
    k23=K2(x_min+i*r,E);

    Y[i]=PAR*NumerovR(i,k21,k22,k23,Y);

    if(i==i_x_m+1) //Función de Onda Derecha en el Matching point
    {
        k21=K2(x_min+(i)*r,E);
        k22=K2(x_min+(i+1)*r,E);
        k23=K2(x_min+(i-1)*r,E);

        Yright=NumerovR(i-1,k21,k22,k23,Y);
    }
}

SlopeRight=PAR*(Y[i_x_m+1]-Yright)/r;

return Yright;
}

void PrintFunc(double Y[])
{
  for(int i=0 ; i<=N+1 ; i++)
 {
    cout << x_min+i*r << "\t" << Y[i] << endl;
 }
}

void Normalizar(double Y[])
{
  double S=0;

 for(int i=0 ; i<=N+1 ; i++)
 {
     S += Y[i]*Y[i]*r;
 }  

S=sqrt(S);

  for (int i=0 ; i<=N+1 ; i++)
 {
     Y[i]=Y[i]/S;
 }

}

double f(double E, double Y[])
{
double F;

F=FuncLeft(E,Y)-PAR*FuncRight(E,Y);

return F;
}

 double Biseccion(double a, double b, double Y[])
 {

  double Tol=0.00001; //Tolerancia para encontrar la raiz

 double RET=-123456789;

 if(f(a,Y)*f(b,Y)<0)
 {
     while(fabs(a-b)>Tol)
    {
         double x_m,fa,fm;

        fa=f(a,Y);
        x_m=(a+b)/2.0;
        fm=f(x_m,Y);
        //fb=f(b);

        if(fa*fm<0)
        {
            b=x_m;
            //RET=b;
        }
        else
        {
            a=x_m;
            //RET=a;
        }
    }
    RET=a;
}   
return RET;
}
```

Basically the code takes all the energies, i.e. `0<E<Vo` and the function "Biseccion" applies the Bisection algorithm between an energy `E` and `E+step`. So the function finds the eigen-energy for which the left and right (from the [Numerov Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerov%27s_method)) wave functions matches.

The code compiles perfectly but the problem arises when I want to plot the odd solutions. I obtain two satisfactory solutions but another two that it's function is continuous but not it's derivative. [Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjwj1.png) of the plot that I obtain.

As you can see, there are two graphs that are not a satisfactory solution to the problem.

I would be very thankful if somebody can help me with this problem.

Comment: So what have you done to try to solve this? You are the best person to figure this out, as the code is quite complex, and you are the only person who fully understands it.

Comment: @user25005 -- one thing you shouldn't do is use doubles and calculation of doubles as loop constraints. Your loops that use a double as a loop counter can run inconsistently due to rounding errors (maybe if you optimized differently or use a different compiler, you get a different number of iterations). `for(double E=0 ; E<=Vo ; E+=paso)` is an example of a loop that introduces rounding errors in the calculation 'E+=paso'

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code. There is an ambiguity in the Eigenfunctions you get since a re-scaled one will also be a solution (before imposing a normalization condition of course).

The matching condition fails in some cases and you don't get a continuous derivative at the matching point, but in those cases you just have to re-scale one of the left or right Eigenfunctions, so a smooth derivative is obtained. Then you normalize the whole thing, and *voilà*.